# Why is selenium not finding an element on a website

Tags: django, selenium, django-testing

I have the following test that I want to run. A payment request is being made from my application. For the user to complete the payment they have to visit a link on a website that processes payments. I want selenium to enter the email address which is required to complete the payment.  I am getting the following error.

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_submit_payment (order.tests.test_views.TestViewsLiveServer)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/patrice/django-apps/dropby/dropby/order/tests/test_views.py", line 222, in test_submit_payment
    username = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('username')
  File "/home/patrice/django-apps/dropby/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/home/patrice/django-apps/dropby/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/patrice/django-apps/dropby/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/patrice/django-apps/dropby/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="username"]
```

Below is my code for the test.

```
def test_submit_payment(self):
    # get the url to goto the payment view submission view
    url = self.live_server_url + reverse('order:payment', kwargs={'pk': self.order.pk})
    self.selenium.get(url)
    # self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='method_of_payment']/option[text()='ecocash']").click()
    phone_number_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name('phone_number')
    phone_number_input.send_keys('0777777777')
    # Submit the form 
    submit_button = self.selenium.find_element_by_id("submit-payment")
    submit_button.click()
    # Now find the url that goes to the paynow website to complete a payment
    complete_payment_url = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('complete-payment-url')
    complete_payment_url.click()
    # Now we are on the paynow website, enter in the email address of the user who is going
    # To make the payment
    username = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('username')
    username.send_keys('abantusoft@gmail.com')
    # Now take the submit button and click it
    login_button = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('login-next')
    login_button.click()
    # Get the payment that was recently created
    payment = Payment.objects.last()
    # Create a url to visit to confirm the payment
    payment_completion_url = self.live_server_url + reverse('order:complete_payment', kwargs={'pk': payment.pk})
    self.selenium.get(payment_completion_url)
    # find the button to confirm the payment and click it
    confirm_payment_button = self.selenium.find_elements_by_id('confirm-payment-button')
    confirm_payment_button.click()
    # Now that we have confirmed the payment
    # check to see if the payment has been paid
    payment = Payment.objects.last()
    self.assertEquals(payment.paid, True, msg='Payment has not been completed')
    # confirm also that the order is ready
    self.assertEquals(payment.order.is_ready, True, msg="Order is not ready, since payment has not been completed")
```

I think maybe the website is selenium protected. Because if I look on the page source I found the element that I am trying to select has the id `username`. I should be able to find it.

```
<form id="login-email">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>
            Email Address
            <input id="username" name="username" type="email" value="">
        </label>
        
        <!-- TO ALLOW CHROME TO AUTOFILL USERNAME -->
        <input type="password" style="display: none">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="login-next" class="btn">Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please share the page URL

Comment: https://www.paynow.co.zw/Payment/ConfirmPayment/11797130

Comment: Maybe you need to add some delay to let the page load?

Comment: Is `login-email` unique?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to wait until the page is loaded.
So add the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
```

before

```
username = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('username')
```

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/patrice/django-apps/dropby/dropby/order/tests/test_views.py", line 222, in test_submit_payment
    self.wait(self.selenium, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username')))
  File "/home/patrice/django-apps/dropby/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ``` I am getting this error now.

Comment: How much wait amount in seconds did you set?

Comment: 10 seconds wait

Comment: Try adding some more, 20 or 30

Comment: Okay let me try that

Comment: I do not see iframes there and I see this element so it should work

Comment: I am still getting the TimeOutException, I tried 20 and 30 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231611/discussion-between-chaulap-and-prophet).